# Can't send mail via c# using monodevelop on linux mint

Tags: c#, linux, email, smtp, smtpclient

I have a function in a large c# project that receives an email and a confirmation code and needs to send an email to that address:

```
public int sendVerificationEmail (string email, int randomNumber)
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient ();
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 10000;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential ("wsep142@gmail.com", "<PASSWORD>");
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage ("wsep142@gmail.com", email, "Registration to the forum system", "This is your authentication code: " + randomNumber.ToString () + ".\n Please enter this link: www.myawesomewebsite.com  and insert the code. \n Thank you and have a great day. \n WSEP142 Forum team.");
        mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        client.Send (mm);
        return 0;
    }
    catch(Exception) 
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This code, using windows sends the mail correctly and everything, but when I try using it on linux (mint) using monodeveloper it stucks and can't send anything..
It doesn't get an exception or anything, just get stucked.
What to do?

Answer (score 0):

If things work on Windows and not in Mint it's not your code that's wrong.  It's something within the Mint environment.  Perhaps a firewall setting blocking outbound traffic on port 25??
As an aside you could always try SendGrid to send the email.  They have a number of libs that are easy to use.  I tend to use this API now whenever I need to send external emails.

Regards
Steve.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to open that port on linux?

Comment: There's a firewall app listed in the Mint system tools.  This should allow you to open ports